# How to append <tbody > to <table> of parent window with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, window

popup.html is popped up by script from parent.html:

```
window.open('popup.html', '', 'width=520, height=300,left=500,top=0');
```

Is it possible for popup.html to operate parent.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better to create a function within parent.html that will do the operation itself.  For example, in parent.html:

```
function addRecordToTable(data)
{
  //your code here
}
```

and in popup.html:

```
window.opener.addRecordToTable(data);
```